# How to bind or reference a UserControl from another UserControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

In my application I have a `UserControl`, that hosts another `UserControl`, like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FooControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp">
    <local:BarControl x:Name="NestedControl" />
</UserControl>
```

Now within the hosted `BarControl`, I want to compute the position of it, relative to the hosting `FooControl` control. Currently I am calling a member of the child control from `FooControl`s code behind, like so:

```
this.NestedControl.ComputeRelativePos(this);
```

and within this method, I compute the position like this:

```
public void ComputeRelativePos(Control relativeTo)
{
    var pos = this.TranslatePoint(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), relativeTo);

    // ...
}
```

Now I want to eliminate this call and re-compute the position from event handlers (like for example `SizeChanged`) of the nested `BarControl`. I want to do this, so that `BarControl` does not require to be hosted within a `FooControl` or another control, explicitly calling `ComputeRelativePos`:

```
public BarControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.SizeChanged += (sender, args) => 
    {
        this.ComputeRelativePos(this.OuterControl);
    };
}
```

However, I am not quite sure how to create a binding for the `OuterControl` property. I have defined the property like so:

```
public Control OuterControl
{
    get { return this.GetValue(OuterControlProperty) as Control; }
    set { this.SetValue(OuterControlProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty OuterControlProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("OuterControl", typeof(Control), typeof(BarControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

and defined the binding in the `FooControl` markup like this:

```
<local:BarControl x:Name="NestedControl" OuterControl="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

but the `OuterControl` does not appear to be set correctly:

```
this.SizeChanged += (sender, args) => this.ComputeRelativePos(this.OuterControl); // this.OuterControl is `null`
```

I also tried binding to the `FooControl` instance name <sup>1</sup>:

```
<local:BarControl x:Name="NestedControl" 
    OuterControl="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Name}" />
```

... so that I can query it from the visual tree (like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198104/find-parent-of-control-by-name)), but it did not work either.

So my general question is, how do I access a parent control, that is bound to a child's property? I would also accept an alternative approach to this problem, since I'm fairly inexperienced with XAML/WPF.

Thanks in advance.

<sup>1</sup> And of course defining the `DependencyProperty` accordingly.

Comment: Did you try `OuterControl="{Binding ElementName=FooControl}"` ?

Comment: Since you are explicitly asking for an alternative approach, you might want to explain why you are doing this at all. A control would usually not know anything about its parent elements.

Comment: @mm8 - I hope I don't confuse things here, but `FooControl` is the name of the control class, not the name of the control itself (i.e. `<local:FooControl x:Name="myname" />`), so wouldn't `ElementName` require the `x:Name` property of the instance?

Comment: @Carsten: Yes, that's correct. So give the outer `UserControl` an x:Name of `FooControl`.

Comment: @Clemens: Sure! I am trying to host multiple GL viewports in a more general "view" control. Viewports can be added/removed/resized dynamically. The view renders to an FBO that spans the whole "outer" control and in order to be able to set the viewports (i.e. `glViewport()`), I need the X/Y coords relative to the view (what I'm asking here) and the height/width, which is trivial (`ActualHeight`, `ActualWidth`).

Comment: And the outer control is not always the direct parent element? Otherwise you could just use the `Parent` property. Or use the VisualTreeHelper class to get it.

Comment: @Clemens: Nope, unfortunately not - it's actually a template in this specific case, but does not need to (for example I want to be able to use the control from different views).

Comment: @mm8: But then I have to rely on the parent control (e.g. the `FooControl`) to be named `FooControl` - introducing a constraint that's not really transparent. If I had to do this, I would rather constraint `BarControl`s to be hosted within a `FooControl` (as I'm already doing now) and query up the visual tree until I find a `UserControl` of type `FooControl` to make it type safe.

Comment: You define the binding in the view that creates the `FooControl` and in this context you know that there is a parent control named whatever. If you use the control in another view, you might bind to something else. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Ok. I would however suggest to use FrameworkElement or UIElement as property type. The Panel classes are not subclasses of Control.

Comment: @mm8: Yes, I see your point.  In this example, however, I define the binding within an unnamed `FooControl`, so I do not know how the actual `x:Name` when defining the binding.

Comment: @Clemens good point, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Carsten: Then you should go with Nawed Nabi Zada's second suggestion.

Comment: @mm8 I did :-) thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to go into the details of what you are doing and why, but to get the dependency property working you have to change:

```
<local:BarControl x:Name="NestedControl" 
OuterControl="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Name}" />
```

to:

```
<local:BarControl x:Name="NestedControl" OuterControl="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

When this is said, your event handler size changed will be hit before the dependency control is set. Dependency properties are set after the control is initialized.

But afterward when you resize you will see that relativeTo is set to FooControl.

Comment: That's great, I could also use this when nesting the control in others by setting `AncestorType=<ParentType>`. Let me do a quick test to see if it works.  Bonus question: Is there something to bind by an ancestors name or class?

Comment: You could bind like @mm8 suggestion using the element name. or Use  AncestorType=local:FooControl to be more specific

Comment: Yep, works as expected. In the `SizeChanged` handler, I check if `OuterControl` is `null`, which as you described is in the first call before initialization has finished and only handle the event, if it's initialized. Works like charm, thanks! :-)